# catkin and CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG

Tags: catkin, cmake

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Should I be able to set `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS_DEBUG` or the variants for the other build types in my `CMakeLists.txt` for caktin packages? It seems to have no effect. Setting `CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS` seems to work, but I want to set different defines depending on the build type.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/221708/catkin-and-cmake_cxx_flags_debug/) by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) on ROS Answers with karma: 4306 on 2015-11-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Yes, it does actually seem to work if you have no typo in `-DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Debug`...

---

Originally posted by [demmeln](https://answers.ros.org/users/1370/demmeln/) with karma: 4306 on 2015-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1